# useRouter issue in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have broken down the problem to see that it is coming from the 1 in y[1]. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1'). I usually do not have the code like this but I did for the sake of disassembling to find the problem. more context it works sometimes and the console.log(y) returns this
Array(2)
0: "chatid"
1: "id"

```js
        const router = useRouter()
        const chatidx = (Object.entries(router.query));
        const y = (chatidx[0]);
        console.log(y)
        console.log(y[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doubting that you don't have any query parameters on the URL.

You should check your URL like below or not

```
test.com/?chatid=id
```

Here is how `router.query` is returned from the above URL

```
{chatid: "id"}
```

Without those, the default value of `router.query` will be `{}` that leads to the error you're facing

```
        const router = useRouter()
        const chatidx = (Object.entries(router.query)); //convert to []
        const y = (chatidx[0]); //no `[0]` value, so it's `undefined`
        console.log(y) //undefined
        console.log(y[1]); //ERROR - try to get `[1]` of an undefined value
```